# The type or namespace name 'MainPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have an app fo windows mobile c# xaml. when I am building solution it gives me this error in the page App.xaml.cs:

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'MainPage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\app5\app5\app5.shared\app.xaml.cs   105 48  App5.WindowsPhone

The code in App.xaml.cs is:

```
   if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments))

            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
```

When MainPage is marked as error. what can be the problem?

Update:
Both the App class and the MainPage class are in the same namespace (App5). The MainPage class is defined in the same folder in `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

Comment: What is the namespace of `MainPage` and `App`?

Comment: the problem is MainPage could not be found. are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

Check the full path of the class name in both your code-behind and your xaml file. They must match!

Also make sure your app.xaml file is referencing the correct URL of Mainpage.